# Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, trigger

I can't figure out what i am missing here - I have this code im using to change lead owner to existing account owner if email domain matches a domain field on account. It works fine - however if a lead comes in without an email im getting an error.

> Apex trigger leadOwnerAssignEmailTrigger caused an unexpected
>   exception, contact your administrator: leadOwnerAssignEmailTrigger:
>   execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to de-reference a null object:
>   Class.leadOwnerAssignEmailHandler.updateLeadOwner: line 21, column 1

**Line 21 is marked with ** in the code below.**

```
public class leadOwnerAssignEmailHandler {
    public static void updateLeadOwner(List<lead> domainList) {

      set<String> domainSet = new set<string>();

     For (lead l:domainList){
      if(l.email !=null && l.email !='')
       domainSet.add(l.Email.split('@').get(1));
     }

      List<Account> accDomainList = [Select Id, OwnerId, domain__c FROM Account 
      WHERE domain__c IN: domainSet];


       Map<String, Id> accountsByDomainMap = new Map<String, Id>();
        if(accDomainList!= null && accDomainList.size()>0) {
            for(Account acc : accDomainList) {
                accountsByDomainMap.put(acc.domain__c,acc.OwnerID);
            }
          }
         for(lead l : domainList) {
            **if(accountsByDomainMap != null && 
        accountsByDomainMap.containskey(l.email.split('@').get(1))) {
                l.ownerID = accountsByDomainMap.get(l.email.split('@').get(1));**
          }
          }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is here `l.email.split('@').get(1)` statement. Seems your email is null here.

Add one more condition to check email is not null. This will solve your issue.

You are just trying to split email with `@`. If there is not `@` and how you will get the First string using `get(1)`

In this case you will get

```
System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 1 error
```

This is the cause I can see so far.